# How to wait on d3.json to finish?

Tags: d3.js

How can I wait for `d3.json` to fill my array `saved_data` before my function `callback` is executed?

I'm using `saved_data` if it is not empty. Otherwise I'm requesting new data and saving it in the `saved_data` variable:

```
if (saved_data.length > 0) {
  callback(null, parse(variable, saved_data)); 
}
else {
  // -------------- Begin Request New Data ------------------
  d3.json(" ... ", 
      function(data) {
        if (!data) return callback(new Error("unable to load data"));   
        saved_data = data; 
  });

  // how to wait on d3.json? before the call back?
  callback(null, parse(variable, saved_data));

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (saved_data.length > 0) {
  callback(null, parse(variable, saved_data)); 
}
else {
// -------------- Begin Request New Data ------------------
  d3.json(" ... ", 
      function(data) {
        if (!data) return callback(new Error("unable to load data"));   
        saved_data = data; 
        // Put it here.
        callback(null, parse(variable, saved_data));
      });
}
```

Put it in the same callback for `d3.json`

Comment: okay thanks! I thought it won't work with passing the extra variable!